# Windows 10 - how to remove specific windows updates?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

in Windows 10,

1)  How can you effectively know/search if a specific update package is installed on your system (i am talking about these update files named like KB123456...)?

2)  And if one is possible, how can you select and completely de-install/remove a specific update package?

3)  Can you even do that in the process of a Clean Install (when using Microsoft's official ISO file), removing your desired updates from the ISO installer file, so that you are installing it directly without them?

4)  Is there any update package that you may know of which has "bugs" and should be avoided to install?

Thanks

Comment: Windows Update history has all the updates you have recently installed.  All known issues are documented by Microsoft [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1909)

Comment: What problem specifically are you trying to solve by removing specific updates?  If you are trying to remove Cumaltive updates, that seems counterproductive, since each cumulative update has all fixes from the previous cumulative update.

Comment: For most computer (especially commercially constructed computers), there are no Windows Updates to avoid. We keep all our computers up to date - we are moving on to V1909 and not seeing any issues. Microsoft very quickly fixes any given widespread problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all installed Windows updates in Add/Remove Programs. While it's not the default uninstaller in Windows 10, but you can open it by typing appwiz.cpl into the Start Menu, Search, or Run. Then you select the Show Installed Updates function.

You can even search for updates by KB number.

However, the comments are correct: you shouldn't have to remove an update unless MS has recommended it as a temporary fix, and if they do recommend this, by the time they've done so they'll have also removed it from all the other things you've mentioned, making me think this isn't the case in your situation.